# How can I play these lectures at 2x speed?

Tags: windows, screen-recorder

I bought hundreds of hours of lecture videos in .exe files (you run the .exe files to play the videos), but the teacher speaks too too slowly, I wish to play them in 2x speed.

Things I have tried and failed:

1. Extract video from the .exe : Tried several apps and couldn't extract any videos. Apparently they're encrypted to avoid pirate.
2. Record them: These .exe files will detect any type of recording apps in the world - if they found you're running any recorder, they wouldn't play. I have tried many recorders.
3. Play them in VMware and record VMware: Nope, they simply don't play in VMware.
4. Change the process name of the recorder app: I don't know how to do that. What I did try was rename the whateverRecorder.exe to a.exe, which didn't work. The process name was unchanged. Btw I'm using Win8.1 x64.

Any ideas would be appreciated !!

Comment: As it stands, this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) I've ignored the XY part & thrown in a quick couple of possibilities as an answer. Could you edit your question to remove the assumed fix & concentrate on the actual issue that needs solving.

Comment: Much better, thanks - though it now makes half my 'quick guess' answer redundant ;)

Answer (score 0):

Quick thoughts -

1) Teamviewer from another machine & record Teamviewer instead.

2) pull the .exe apart & run the video portion in VLC, which has vari-speed.

Google found this for pulling resources out of .exes, but I've not tested it - http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/resources_extract.html

Comment: Thanks, I edited about pulling out the video. I'll try Teamviewer tomorrow.